# "This" reference in ecmascript compared to vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i am somewhat new in javascript and recently started using ecmascript6. I'm wondering how to write something like this in ES6?

```
'/1/2/3'.split('/').slice(0, this.length-1).join("/");
```

This gives "/1/2", since

```
this.length == '/1/2/3'.split('/')
```

but this doesn't sadly work in ecmascript, since 'this' is undefined. Is there a way to write in similar way?

Thank you.

Comment: ECMAScript is a *specification*, JavaScript is one *implementation* of the specification. ES6 is the 6th version of the specification. What do you expect `this` to refer to here? Please provide more information.

Comment: ?? What is it that you expect `this` to be in that first code sample? What it definitely *won't* be is a reference to that string `'/1/2/3'`.

Comment: Pointy, to ["", "1", "2", "3"], e.g result of the previous function- split

Comment: @TheRedHerring42: That's not how ECMAScript/JavaScript works. If it "works" for you in a particular instance, then only coincidentally (not because JavaScript has different behavior than ECMAScript (because it doesn't, JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript)).

Comment: It will not be a reference to that array either. It'll be whatever `this` is in the context of that overall expression, and that depends on where the code is and other things. That fact is true for any ECMAScript version.

Comment: If you want to learn more about how `this` works, have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Pointy, Felix Kling, ok thanks. I will read more about it then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*ECMAScript* is a standard. *JavaScript* is the implementation of that standard by Mozilla.

You might want to try the following:

```
var tmp = '/1/2/3'.split('/');
tmp.slice(0,tmp.length-1).join('/') // do somthing with me
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want remove the last item of the array, you can do that without needing a tmp variable.

```
'/1/2/3'.split('/').slice(0,-1).join("/")
```

[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) accepts a negative index for the second (*and first*) parameter

> As a negative index, `end` indicates an offset from the end of the sequence. `slice(2,-1)` extracts the third element through the second-to-last element in the sequence.